# How to use Python/Curl to access LinkedIn and view a friend's full profile?

Tags: python, curl, network-programming, linkedin-api

A Linkedin friend's full profile is not viewable without login to our Linkedin account. Is it possible to use cookie or any other alternative way without a browser to do that?

Any tips are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out `python-linkedin` package [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-linkedin/4.0)

> LinkedIn REST API uses Oauth 2.0 protocol for authentication. In order
>   to use the LinkedIn API, you have an application key and application
>   secret. You can get more detail from [here](http://developers.linkedin.com/documents/authentication).

Comment: Nice information! Alternatively, can we simply simulate a browser with Python or Curl using cookie for the authentication?

Comment: @OsirisXu, I don't think with just cookie you can manipulate the LinkedIn's sign in otherwise it is vulnerable to session hijacking.
Is there any special reason you have to use this combination?

Comment: that said however, using python + curl to do the oauth manually is possible, just passing client credentials and get the token from LinkedIn. You can read their official API for more details

Comment: Thank you for the tips. The question about LinkedIn API is that it seems doesn't trigger "who's viewed my profile". But I do want my friends know that I viewed their profiles. Currently we can use any web browser to trigger it. Can we make this with Python+Curl?

Comment: I never tried the *who's viewed my profile*, if you're not in hurry I can take a look this weekend and perhaps write a whole script for it :), what exact information do you need to access?

Comment: That would be great! What I want is very simple, I just want to fetch each friend's headline or current title, and let them know I have viewed their profile (namely in their Notifications center, I will be listed as one who "viewed his/her profile"). Looking forward for your update!

Comment: Hey OsirisXu and @Anzel , where did you get to with your attempt to notify other users that you "visit" their profile programatically?

Comment: @Diego, I have not yet since looked any further to this issue. But at a quick glance on their API docs, it seems you may be able to get the [**related-profile-views**](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/full-profile) to achieve this

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Anzel, but related-profile-views API allows to read past profile view, but not trigger a new view (and therefore notify the user that I visited their profile programmatically). Unless I pop up a new window and load their profile, but then I'll need a browser to do it. Ideally I wanted to achieve it via backend, cURL and cookies, but it it's not as simple as it sounds.